# Motorola X Broken Digitizer

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen, moto-x

A while ago, I dropped my Moto X, and my digitizer slowly stopped working. I can no longer see my screen or unlock it. Is there anyway that I could get the files off of the phone without replacing the digitizer? It is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that moto x supports usb-otg. so you can connect a mouse and copy the files to an sd card or send them through bluetooth to another device.